TypeError: Tuple indices must be integers or slices, not dict
I am trying to add a learning rate scheduler with a finBERT model. However I am getting this error " TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not dict" while training.
    #convert to dataset object required for hugging transformers
    train_Dataset=Dataset.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'text':X_train,'label':y_train}))
    test_Dataset=Dataset.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'text':X_test,'label':y_test}))

    #FINBERT TEXT REPRESENTATION
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("yiyanghkust/finbert-tone")

    def tokenize_function(df):
        return tokenizer(df["text"],padding="max_length",truncation=True,     max_length=512)

    tokenized_train=train_Dataset.map(tokenize_function,batched=True)
    tokenized_test=test_Dataset.map(tokenize_function,batched=True)

    #DATASET for LEARNING RATE SCHEDULER 
    class CustomDataset(Dataset):
        def __init__(self, texts, labels, tokenizer):
            self.texts = texts
            self.labels = labels
            self.tokenizer = tokenizer

        def __len__(self):
            return len(self.texts)

        def __getitem__(self, idx):
            # If idx is a list (batch), handle it
            if isinstance(idx, list):
                texts = [self.texts[i] for i in idx]
                labels = [self.labels[i] for i in idx]
                encoded = self.tokenizer(
                    texts,  # Process the entire batch
                    padding='max_length',
                    truncation=True,
                    max_length=512,
                    return_tensors="pt"
                )
                labels = torch.tensor(labels, dtype=torch.float)
                return {key: val for key, val in encoded.items()}, labels
            else:
                # Single item case
                encoded = self.tokenizer(
                    self.texts[idx],  # Single string
                    padding='max_length',
                    truncation=True,
                    max_length=512,
                    return_tensors="pt"
                )
                label = torch.tensor(self.labels[idx], dtype=torch.float)
                return {key: val.squeeze(0) for key, val in encoded.items()},     label


    #fucntion to pass on a list of items to get item
    def custom_collate_fn(batch):
        inputs, labels = zip(*batch)
        # Batch tokenization
        batched_inputs = {key: torch.stack([input_dict[key] for input_dict in inputs]) for key in inputs[0]}
        # Batch labels
        batched_labels = torch.tensor(labels, dtype=torch.float)
        return batched_inputs, batched_labels

    train_dataset = CustomDataset(X_train.tolist(),y_train.tolist(),tokenizer)
    test_dataset = CustomDataset(X_test.tolist(), y_test.tolist(), tokenizer)
    train_loader =        DataLoader(train_dataset,batch_size=5,shuffle=True,collate_fn=custom_collate_fn)
    test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset,batch_size=5,collate_fn=custom_collate_fn)

    #FINE TUNE the FINBERT model

    #no feature engineering required as finbert tokenizer is built to capture the sematinc and context meanings
    model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("yiyanghkust/finbert-tone",num_labels=1,
    ignore_mismatched_sizes=True)

    #incorporate scheduler into training loop
    device=torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
    model.to(device)

    #intialize optimizer and cyclic schedulet to control the learning rate
    optimizer=AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-5)  # Initial learning rate
    scheduler = CyclicLR(optimizer,base_lr=1e-6,max_lr=1e-4,step_size_up=100,mode='triangular')

    #TRAINING MODEL
    for epoch in range(3): 
        model.train()
        for batch_idx,(inputs,labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
            inputs={key:val.to(device) for key,val in inputs.items()}
            labels=labels.to(device)

             optimizer.zero_grad()
             outputs=model(**inputs,labels=labels.unsqueeze(1))
             loss=outputs.loss
             loss.backward()
             optimizer.step()

            #step teh scheduler
            scheduler.step()

            if batch_idx%10==0:
                print(f"Epoch {epoch}, Batch {batch}, Loss: {loss.item()}, LR: {scheduler.get_last_lr()}")

I am getting the following error while running this code.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 1
----> 1 for data in train_loader:
      2         input,label=data

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:630, in _BaseDataLoaderIter.__next__(self)
    627 if self._sampler_iter is None:
    628     # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
    629     self._reset()  # type: ignore[call-arg]
--> 630 data = self._next_data()
    631 self._num_yielded += 1
    632 if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \
    633         self._IterableDataset_len_called is not None and \
    634         self._num_yielded > self._IterableDataset_len_called:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:673, in _SingleProcessDataLoaderIter._next_data(self)
    671 def _next_data(self):
    672     index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 673     data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    674     if self._pin_memory:
    675         data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data, self._pin_memory_device)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py:50, in _MapDatasetFetcher.fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     48 if self.auto_collation:
     49     if hasattr(self.dataset, "__getitems__") and self.dataset.__getitems__:
---> 50         data = self.dataset.__getitems__(possibly_batched_index)
     51     else:
     52         data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py:2747, in Dataset.__getitems__(self, keys)
   2745 """Can be used to get a batch using a list of integers indices."""
   2746 batch = self.__getitem__(keys)
-> 2747 n_examples = len(batch[next(iter(batch))])
   2748 return [{col: array[i] for col, array in batch.items()} for i in range(n_examples)]

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not dict

During debugging, the train_loader should have been a tuple.I ensured getitem() also returns a tuple for batched and individual indices. I do not understand where the occurence of dict is or how it is so?
I tried to simply get teh data from train_loader with the following code:
for data in train_loader:
    input,label=data

Yet, I am getting the same error as above.

Maybe the first element of the tuple should be the tuple too?
